# IntelliJ 14.0.2 breaks GWT super dev mode code server

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

After updating IntelliJ from 14.0.1 to 14.0.2 the GWT Code Server stopped working.
Anyone that have the same issue?

I get the following **error**:

```
11:51:27,454  WARN ServletHandler:578 - Error for /
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.http.gzip.CompressedResponseWrapper.newCompressedStream(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;JII)Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/gzip/AbstractCompressedStream;
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.gzip.CompressedResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(CompressedResponseWrapper.java:342)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.PageUtil.sendJsonAndHtml(PageUtil.java:89)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.doGet(WebServer.java:174)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.handleRequest(WebServer.java:158)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.access$000(WebServer.java:65)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer$1.doGet(WebServer.java:123)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1367)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that jetty server was not updated in my local maven cache.
When I removed in and let maven download it again, it worked!!